# HP P440/2gb RAID controller with Samsung pm1643 for production environment

Tags: raid, ssd

I'm planning to buy two refurbished servers to run as HA hypervisors.

I've found DL380p G9 which features a P440/2gb RAID controller. I also found some new Samsung pm1643 SSDs in very competitive prices. I'm planning to use 2 drives with RAID 1 configuration.

Since I only have experience with Intel's older SMC drivers, O would like to know if these drivers are fast enough to support multiple VM's (lots of random read/writes) while at the same time reliable enough to be used in a production environment.

Comment: As noted in other comments to answer, check that the drives will be recognized by the RAID controller. Non-HP hardware can be problematic. Even if same OEM, firmware can be different on HP branded drive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use non-HP labeled drives for sure, but you’re going to void the warranty (I doubt you have anything left...) and you’re going to lose at least some of the monitoring & reporting capabilities. Either way if you’ll stick with some decent Enterprise SSD with power loss protection (This is your case so far...) you’ll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite vague, but [Samsung PM1643 is a relatively fast enterprise drive](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi.static/Product_Brief_Smasung_PM1643_SAS_SSD_1805.pdf), albeit a read-centric/mixed one (1 DWPD). Putting aside recent NVMe drives, is it quite performant as it provides 2x 12 Gb/s SAS 3.0 links.

So it should have no issue running multiple virtual machines with light/medium loads but it clearly all depends on the expected/actual load.

HP P440 is a good controller, but you should double-check its compatibility with the selected Samsung drives (ie: be sure it will accept non-HP branded drives).

Comment: that's nice to hear. do you believe that the p440/2gb controller is sufficient or should i upgrade to a p880/4gb?

Comment: P440 is a good controller, but you should double-check its compatibility with the selected Samsung drives.

Comment: It should be compatible as the p440 supports 12gbps sata disks. Is there anything I should look for?

Comment: Some RAID controllers have the (bad) habit of only working with vendor-branded HDDs. DELL did this in the past, and I read that some current HP controller do the same. However, as this behavior is firmware-dependent, you should check your (updated) controller docs.